# Pegar nome da tag span

Tags: javascript

Preciso pegar o nome gerado dentro da id="pegarnome" e colocar dentro da id="nome", fiz o código abaixo, porém não deu certo.

A tag do span id="pegarnome" gera o nome do cliente, no caso Fulano da Silva e depois com o script retornaria apenas o primeiro nome.

```
<span data-customer="name" id="pegarnome" ></span>
<span id="nome"></span>

<script>

    var str = document.getElementById("pegarnome").innerHTML;
    var res = str.split(" ",1);
    document.getElementById("nome").innerHTML = res;

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>    
    var str = document.getElementById("pegarnome").innerHTML;
    var arr = str.split(" ");
    var res = arr[0];
    document.getElementById("nome").innerHTML = res;
</script>
```

O Split retorna um array de String, você pode usa-lo passando para o elemento o primeiro índice do array, que seria o primeiro nome.

Comment: Funcionou em partes, nome gerando dentro da span só aparece depois do script pelo que percebi, ou seja ele não pega atributo nenhum. Eu testei colocando um nome manualmente dentro da span e funcionou.